# jQuery: select an element's class and id at the same time?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I've got some links that I want to select class and id at the same time.

This is because I've got 2 different behaviours. When a class of links got one class name they behave in one way, when the same clas of links got another class name they behave differently. The class names are switch with jquery.

So I have to be able to select a links class AND id at the same time. Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
 $("a .save #country")
```

without any result.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#country.save")...
```

OR

```
$("a#country.save")...
```

OR

```
$("a.save#country")...
```

as you prefer.

So yes you can specify a selector that has to match ID *and* class (and potentially tag name and anything else you want to throw in).

Comment: So basically its like : $("#a .b") means element with class b inside element with id a. $("#a.b") means element with class b and id a. The trick is the space between #a and .b

Comment: Must be careful that you use id selector before class otherwise it does not work. Example: $(".save#country")... does not return results.

Answer (score 54):

Just to add that the answer that Alex provided worked for me, and not the one that is highlighted as an answer.

This one didn't work for me

```
$('#country.save')
```

But this one did:

```
$('#country .save')
```

so my conclusion is to use the space. Now I don't know if it's to the new version of jQuery that I'm using (1.5.1), but anyway hope this helps to anyone with similar problem that I've had.

**edit:** Full credit for explanation (in the comment to Alex's answer) goes to Felix Kling who says:

*The space is the descendant selector, i.e. A B means "Match all elements that
match B which are a descendant of elements matching A". AB means "select all 
element that match A and B". So it really depends on what you want to achieve. `#country.save` and `#country .save` are not equivalent.*

Comment: Is the problem that you said "countery" instead of "country"?

Answer (score 8):

It will work when adding space between id and class identifier

`$("#countery .save")...`

Comment: actually this worked for me, as it was not working like $('#countery.save') so thank you!

Comment: I've found sometimes it's picky about the space. like 
$(.selector > .item#id) works, but $(.selector > .item #id) doesnt.

Comment: The space is the *descendant selector*, i.e. `A B` means "Match all elements that match B which are a descendant of elements matching A". `AB` means "select all element that match A and B". So it really depends on what you want to achieve. `#countery.save` and `#countery .save` are not equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a.save, #country")
```

will select both "a.save" class and "country" id.

Answer (score 3):

In the end the same rules as for css apply.

So I think [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) could be of some valuable use.

Comment: Could you summarize the contents of your reference?

Comment: Actually, according to http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ jQuery has some selectors of its own; also, it doesn't actually say that all CSS 1-3 selectors are supported...

Comment: @SamB You're right but, it does say it _borrows_ from CSS 1-3 AND adds its own.  I still think the link to the W3C stuff is valid to this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

How about this code?

```
$("a.save#country")
```