# Can't select jquery element by both class and numeric ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
$(".associated_requests")
[<div class=​"associated_requests" id=​"0">​</div>​, 
<div class=​"associated_requests" id=​"1">​</div>​, 
<div class=​"associated_requests" id=​"2">​</div>​, 
<div class=​"associated_requests" id=​"3">​</div>​]

$(".associated_requests#0")
[]
```

Am I doing something syntactically wrong? Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944302/jquery-select-an-elements-class-and-id-at-the-same-time) it seems like this should be possible.

EDIT: The following also fail:

```
$(".associated_requests #0")
[]
$("#0 .associated_requests")
[]
$("#0.associated_requests")
[]
```

Comment: What happens when you use `#0.associated_request`? Also, try to avoid numbers as `id`s, they are not valid in HTML4.

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, selecting them along with a class is pointless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prior to HTML5, `id`s cannot start with numbers. Change it to start with a letter. i.e. `item0`, `item1`, `item2` etc.

Comment: @j08691 however without an html5 doctype it will not work. This is most likely the case.

Comment: @KevinB - then it wouldn't really be HTML5 would it?

Comment: @j08691 What does that have to do with anything? The code above is failing because he is not using HTML5 and his id starts with a number. If he was using HTML5 he would get a single element.

Comment: @KevinB - why technically not legal in < HTML5, most browsers will still interpret it correctly.

Comment: Too many browsers will puke and too many scripts will look weird to have digits as ID or name. I would avoid it like the plague

Comment: I am using HTML5 for my rails app. Still, the number id's weren't working for some reason. I changed it to start with letters and it now works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do `$('#item0')`? .. You should not have duplicate id's

Answer (score 0):

```
var item0 = document.getElementById('0');

var item1 = document.getElementById('1');
```

or you can just rename your id instead of just a number add like `id="id-0"`

so you can select it as `$('#id-0.associated_content')`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select the divs based on their indices, as an *alternative* you can use `eq()` method:

```
$('.associated_requests').eq(0) // selects the first one
$('.associated_requests').eq(1) // selects the second one
```