# Parse HTML inside of <Body>...</> Tag

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, jsoup

All- I have the following code:

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {    
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://scores.espn.go.com/
                                 nfl/gamecast?
                                 gameId=320909007',%20'gamecast320909007"
                               ).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        docTitle = doc.select("head").first().text();
        return null;    
    }
}
```

I get the output "NFL Gamecast - Chicago vs Green Bay" (Green Bay won by the way). That is great but when I tried to get the actual score I could not figure out how. My problem was I was trying to replace "head" with `<div id="awayScoreBox" class="vscorebox">...</div>` (this is under the `<Body>` Tag). So following the format of using the "head" tag I tried this:

```
docTitle = doc.select("div id="awayScoreBox" class="vscorebox"").first().text();
return null;
```

As you can imagine I got a syntax error but could not figure out why. I realize that I might have to specify that this is under the `<Body>` tag but I could not find any information on how to go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please get used to call it <body> tag, not <Body> tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351857/is-html-case-sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a css selector for [selecting id and class at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944302/jquery-select-an-elements-class-and-id-at-the-same-time) so it's

```
doc.select("div#awayScoreBox.vscorebox");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got a NullPointerException. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved that. Now the application loads but shows a blank where the info should be. Might just be because there is no info to display but seems unlikely...Let me try a different tag...

Comment: there is no text inside that div

Comment: So, are you saying that there are only numbers (the score)?

Comment: i donwloaded that link but it's empty inside that div, no text or number.

Comment: i think the score or whatever you are looking is injected at runtime using javascript.

Comment: Ok. Let me try a different website and a different tag.

Comment: Finally. It worked on stackoverflow on the top w=questions. Thanks you so much for your help. Have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the quotes. You are currently using this.

```
docTitle = doc.select("div id="awayScoreBox" class="vscorebox"").first().text();
return null;
```

Change `doc.select` part to this.

```
doc.select("div id=\"awayScoreBox\" class=\"vscorebox\"").first().text();
```

This is why you get a `SyntaxException`.