# How to select an element with dynamically generated class and id at the same time?

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML**

```
120:    $seperator= "<SEPERATOR>";
121:    echo "<div class='optionBox' onClick='selectOther(this.id)' id='".$OPid.$seperator.$OPlayer2ID."' >".$OPlayer2nam."</div>";
```

**Jquery**

```
function selectOther(evalOTHERID){
   $("div[.*'selected'#'"+evalOTHERID+"']").css('opacity', '1');
   $("div[id='"+evalOTHERID+"']").css('opacity', '0.08');
   $("div[id='"+evalOTHERID+"']").addClass( "selected" );   
}
```

the HTML line #120 and #121 are in a while loop to generate selectable boxes, something like the one bellow

```
=====   =====   =====
=43 =   =44 =   =45 = 
=====   =====   =====
```

the opacity will be changed to 0.08 on click on each selectable boxes, My problem is how to deselect the previously selected one ? I tried to use the suggested solutions on  [jQuery: select an element's class and id at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944302/jquery-select-an-elements-class-and-id-at-the-same-time)  but it seems that there is something wrong with my integration.

I also tried to change it to:

```
    $("div[class*='selected'][id='"+evalOTHERID+"']").css('opacity', '1');
```

But it still won't change the opacity of the selected one back to 1.

I have googled the question tried to find an answer for it, it's true that there are bunch of solutions but I am new in web programming, and not able to integrate the correctly. there is no error in console by the way.

Please tell me in what way I can get the ID of the element that has class selected? I will be appreciated.

Please help me to edit the question if it isn't really clear, I'll learn more things then. Appreciated.

Comment: Make a fiddle to illustrate the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ok ill make now, I have the data coming from my DB and PHP HTML mixed, how to put this kind of code in fiddle, is a new question

Comment: It's a matter of your jQuery selector not working, you don't need to generate the page, just make an example of what the page would look like when you call the function.

Comment: yes its the jQuery selector, all I need to do is to find the ID of the element has class like "selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify things a little bit by passing the dom node like:

```
onClick='selectOther(this)'
```

Then we wrap it in jQuery `$(elem)` and solve the problem:

```
function selectOther(elem){
   $(elem).toggleClass("selected");

    if( $(elem).hasClass("selected") ){
        $(elem).css('opacity', '0.08');
    } else {
        $(elem).css('opacity', '1');
    } 

}
```