# jquery: select and elements class and id at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Edit 1** (Sorry for the confusion)

```
$(this).hide();
```

will work for this particular id. But i think i coundnt put my query clearly. Although I got the answer, I have edited it now for future reference.

---

I have elements like this

```
<img src='images/star-transparent.png' id='star_transparent-1' width='30' height='30' class='star_transparent' />
<img src='images/star-transparent.png' id='star_transparent-2' width='30' height='30' class='star_transparent' />
<img src='images/star-blue.png' id='star_blue-1' width='30' height='30' class='star_blue' />
<img src='images/star-blue.png' id='star_blue-2' width='30' height='30' class='star_blue' />
```

and so on..
What I want is **trigger onclick event to the class, and hide the transparent image which was clicked and show the colored one**. My current jquery is -

```
$('.star_transparent').click(function() {
    var star_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).hide();
    //how to write the 'id' with 'class' in the following line
    $('.star_blue').show();
});
```

In one [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944302/jquery-select-an-elements-class-and-id-at-the-same-time), the proposed answer said to use something like -

```
$("#star_transparent-1.star_transparent");
or
$("#star_transparent-1 .star_transparent");
```

But, in my case `star_transparent-1` or `star_transparent-2` i.e. **ID is itself a variable which is derived from class.click** function. So how should I write that?

Also, in the above mentioned proposed answer, it was said that `#star_transparent-1.star_transparent` and `#star_transparent-1 .star_transparent` are two different things. it was quoted as -

> The space is the descendant selector, i.e. A B means "Match all
>   elements that match B which are a descendant of elements matching A".
>   AB means "select all element that match A and B".

But, i am sorry to say, I didnt understand it. If anybody can explain it more easily, that would be a great help.

thanks.
regards

Dr. Atul Tiwari

Comment: why don't you use, `$('.star_transparent').click(function() { $(this).hide() }`

Comment: What do you want to do with id of selected image?

Comment: Can $(this).hide(); within the click event will help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use keyword `this` itself to hide image which was clicked.

```
$('.star_transparent').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Selector using id:

```
$('.star_transparent').click(function() {
    var star_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+star_id+'.star_transparent').hide();
});
```

Comment: The second one doesn't make any sense.. :\

Comment: `$(this).hide();` is best, However as IDs must be unique you can simply use `$('#'+star_id).hide()`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy sorry for the confusion, but I needed the second one.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari, Why do you need second one As ID must be unique you can simply use `$('#'+star_id).hide()` there is no point using `'.star_transparent'` with ID selector.

Comment: @Satpal sorry sir, actually i needed `$('#'+star_id+'.star_blue').show()`. and yes you are right `$(this).hide();` will alone work for `.star_transparent`. see my edited question. thanks.
and yes i am splitting the `star_id` just to get the number 1 or 2, so that i can use it display the corresponding colored one.

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be multiple elements with the same id in your code.

Comment: @DavidThomas The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-getElBId) clearly says "Behavior is not defined if more than one element has the same ID".

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different ids you can easily use it to hide.

$('.star_transparent').click(function(evt) {

```
var star_id = $(evt.currentTarget).attr('id');
$('#' + star_id).hide();
```

});

Thanks