# Jquery each within each to move to parent

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I'm not sure if i'm doing this correctly but I have this list of content that needs to be injected into a form generated by the plugin.

I'm using this code to determain each part of the form and place the content in the list that matches the output.

```
$('.vfb-page-section').each(function(){
    var sectionName = $('.vfb-page-title',this).text().toLowerCase();
    console.log(sectionName);
    // Get the section name and make it lowercase to match the div class name.

    $('.vfb-fieldType-radio',this).each(function(){
        var groupID = $(this).attr('id').replace('vfbField','');
        console.log(groupID);
        // Get the ID number of the group of inputs.

        $('input',this).each(function(){
            var inputID = $(this).attr('id').replace('vfb-field-'+groupID+'-','');
            console.log(inputID);
            // Get the ID of the input.

            var candidate = $('.cat-'+sectionName+' #'+inputID).clone();
            //Build the selector to find the correct div.
            console.log(candidate);
            $(this).parent().before(candidate);
            // The div needs to be appended to the parent of the input
        });
    });
});
```

The div on the page has something like this:

```
<div class="cat-sectionname" id="2">some content</div>
```

So far i've managed to get the first group to have it's content moved to the right input parents. But the next groupID nothing seems to be found.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your candidate selector is looking for 2 elements instead of 1 with the given class & id. Remove the space & it should find the element:

```
var candidate = $('#'+inputID+'.cat-'+sectionName).clone();
```

The space means that it looks for an element with the id inside an element with the class. [Related answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1944316)

Comment: Sorry for the late response but you were right, the space is what got me.