# jquery trigger a click based on class and id

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of links on a page:

```
<a href='#' class='link' id='1'>1</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='2'>2</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='3'>3</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='4'>4</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='5'>5</a>
```

These links open a modal that provides users a bunch of data. A user can edit some data and submit a form in this modal.  After they are done, I want to reload the data in this modal.

how can i trigger a click based on the class and the id.  Basically in laymans turns I want to:

```
$('.link' //That has id 4//).trigger('click');
```

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, why would the class be necessary?

Comment: [Various solutions available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944302/jquery-select-an-elements-class-and-id-at-the-same-time)

Comment: See edits.  I may be going about what I am trying to do incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to have numeric IDs but this should work `$("#4").click()`

```js
$(".link").on("click",function() { console.log(this.id) }); // show it works

$("#4").click()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' class='link' id='1'>1</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='2'>2</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='3'>3</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='4'>4</a>
<a href='#' class='link' id='5'>5</a>
```